# Finding rogue process spawning short lived WMIC.exe commands

Tags: wmi, wmic

There is a rogue process on my system spawning very CPU intensive WMIC.exe processes. They are so short lived that I can't seem to interact with them before they finish, but I believe they are causing a lot of system instability.

Resource monitor sorted by CPU usage looks like this:
[image: Resource Monitor]

And of course, that active WMIC process died immediately after taking that picture (it took a few attempts to even get a picture with an active WMIC process).

I tried to catch it (somewhat ironically) by using Get-WmiObject:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name LIKE '%wmic%'" | Select-Object Name,CommandLine,ParentProcess
```

I ran that command a few hundred times, and never managed to catch any WMIC process other than the command I just ran.

Is there some log or something where I can see information on finished processes? Or any way to get an idea of what is launching these WMIC.exe processes, or what they are doing?

Comment: Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using "Process Monitor", as HelpingHand suggested in a comment. Process Monitor logs process starts, and so I filtered down to processes with a name of "WMIC", and operations of "Process Start".

This made it possible to identify the ParentProcess of the WMIC.exe process, which I dug into using:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name LIKE '%wmic%'" | Select-Object Name,CommandLine,ParentProcess
```

Thanks HelpingHand!